# jquery how to invoke code after a dialog dom is done

Tags: jquery

i have this

HTML

```
<div id="dDiv" title="a dialog that contains stuff">
```

JS

```
$( "#dDiv" ).dialog();      
$( "#dDiv" ).ready(function(){
    func1();
    func2();
});
```

What i am trying to accomplish is to call func1 and func2 after jquery finishes configuring everything at dDiv.

Am i doing it right?

thanks

Comment: I would recommend using the `create` or `open` event provided by the widget.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace thanks